# Declare array with constant (not literal) as dimension specifier

Tags: arrays, indexing, rust, declaration

The following code works, but to easily change the size of the array and the index range of the loops, can the variable `max` be used to specify the dimensions of the array?

```
fn main() {
    let max: i64 = 3;

    let mut arr2: [[f64; 3]; 3] = [[0.0; 3]; 3]; //replace 3 by max?
    // let mut arr2: [[f64; max]; max] = [[0.0; max]; max]; //does not work

    let pi: f64 = 3.1415926535;
    let max2 = max as usize;

    for ii in 0..max2 {
        for jj in 0..max2 {
            let i = ii as f64;
            let j = jj as f64;
            arr2[ii][jj] = ((i + j) * pi * 41.0).sqrt().sin();
            println!("arr2[{}][{}] is {}", ii, jj, arr2[ii][jj]);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the commented out line for the declaration I get this error:

```
error[E0513]: no type for local variable 10
 --> <anon>:6:32
  |
6 |     let mut arr2: [[f64; max]; max] = [[0.0; max]; max]; //does not work
  |                                ^^^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Rust must be declared with a fixed size known at compile time.

If the size is indeed known at compile time, then define a constant instead of a variable:

```
const MAX: usize = 3;
```

If the size is not known at compile time, use a `Vec` instead.

Comment: This was the solution I was searching for. The constant MAX now replaces all instances of 3, max and max2.